# Proof: Continuity from above - how to take the limit outside of measure function?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, functions, continuity

**Need to prove:**

$\\ \mu ( \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} M_{n} ) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(M_{n}) 
\\where \ M_1 \supseteq M_2 \supseteq M_3 \supseteq \ ...$

**Here's what I tried:**

$ \boxed {w.k.t, from \textbf{ Continuity from below}, \\ \mu(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_{n}) - (1)
 \\
 where \ E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq E_3 \subseteq \ ... \\[.1in]
And, \\
\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} E_{n} - (2)
\\ where \ B_{i} = E_{i} - E_{i - 1}.
}\\
\boxed{ By \textbf{ De'morgans law}, \\
\mu(\ (\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n})^{'} \ ) = \mu( \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}^{'} ) \ - (3)} \\
Proving \ \mu ( \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} M_{n} ) \ is \ the \ same \ as \ proving \  \mu ( \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}^{'} )
\\ since, E_{1}^{'} \supseteq E_{2}^{'} \supseteq E_{3}^{'} \supseteq ... \\[.2in]
Using \ (3), \ \\
\mu(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}^{'}) = \mu((\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n})^{'}) \\
Substituting \ (2) \ in \ the \ above  \ eq., \\
\mu(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}^{'}) =  \mu(\lim_{n \to \infty} E_{n}^{'})\\[.3in]
The \ issue \ here \ is \ that, I \ need \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_{n}^{'}) \ and \ not \ \mu(\lim_{n \to \infty} E_{n}^{'}). \\ I'm \ not \ sure \ whether \ it's \ okay \ to \ take \ the \ limit \ outside \ of \ the \ \mu  \ function.\\[.3in]
Also, \ in \ Continuity \ from \ below, \\ it's \ possible \ to \ write \ \mu(E_{1} \cup E_{2}) => \mu(B_{1} + B_{2}) = \mu(B_{1}) + \mu(B_{2}) \\ where \ B_{i} = E_{i} - E_{i-1} and \ using \ that \ we \ can \ prove \ \mu(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_{n}) \\
but \ for \ \mu((B_{1} + B_{2})^{'}) \neq \mu(B_{1}^{'}) + \mu(B_{2}^{'}), \ so \ i'm \ facing \ difficulty \ to \ prove \ it..
$

Comment: This  is false for a general measure but it is true for finite measures.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your reply. Got you. 
It's just that I'm stuck at proving this, it would be great if you can also help to prove this using De'morgans theorem and the result from "Continuity from below".

Comment: Assuming by $E_1 + E_2$ you mean $E_1 \cup E_2$, it's false in general that $\mu(E_1 \cup E_2) = \mu(E_1) + \mu(E_2)$. It is true if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint, but that's not the case here. In general all you can say is that $\mu(E_1 \cup E_2) \leq \mu(E_1) + \mu(E_2)$.

Comment: @Bungo You're right! Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example $M_n=(n,\infty)$ shows that this is false in general.

If $\mu$ is a finite measure (or at least $\mu (M_1) <\infty$) you can prove this as follows: $M_1\setminus M_n$ is an increasing sequence . By continuity from below we get  $\lim \mu (M_1\setminus M_n)=\mu (\bigcup (M_1\setminus M_n)=\mu (M_1-\bigcap M_n)$. This  gives $\lim [\mu(M_1)-\mu (M_n)]=\mu (M_1)-\mu( \bigcap M_n)$. Can you  finish?

Comment: Thank you for showing this approach. I've continued your lines and yes it shows the proof. I'm still curious to know whether there is a way to show the proof through the method handled in the question.

Comment: @DeepakS.M Your approach doesn't work because it doesn't make use of finiteness (which is essential).

Comment: I feel a bit confused.. Are we not using Infinite union and infinite intersection in your answer? Can you show me where we're using the finiteness? Also, finiteness is essential in this proof only, right? Or is it essential to use finiteness in all the proofs involving sets?

Comment: @DeepakS.M When I said finiteness is essential I meant that $\mu (M_1) <\infty$ (or $\mu (M_n) <\infty$  for some $n$ ) is essential.